# The convolution of an unbounded-support function with itself

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Assume the continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has an unbounded support with nonzero measure. Let $g=f\ast f$, where $\ast$ denotes the convolution operator. Is it possible for $g$ to have a bounded support?

Comment: Take a function that is non-zero on a set with measure zero, then its convolution with itself will be zero. Don't know about continuous functions, though.

Comment: @jMdA Yes, you are right. But I meant actually for a function whose support has non-zero measure. I will edit the question to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Concentrate the mass of the support in a bounded set, then make the support unbounded by introducing nonzero values at every integer. This is again a trivial example.

Comment: @jMdA Yes, you are right. maybe you should write it as an answer than a comment. However, do you have any idea about continuous functions?

Comment: I really don't, if I figure the continuous case out, I'll add an answer. I feel like that's probably more in the spirit of the question.

Comment: @jMdA thank you so much. I appreciate that